# NoClassDefFoundError in Glassfish :(

Tags: java, glassfish, netbeans-7, jodconverter

I have this issue bothering me for quite something time.

I have java app developed using netbeans, and deployed on glassfish 3. This part of the code used to work before but now for some reason it is not working. I am using JODConvertor and i can see the library available both in the lib folder and in the war file after deployment.

I have read similar questions on the site, but its not working. I even uninstalled and reinstalled the IDE and the Application Server but to no avail .

Please i need your help.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/star/lang/XEventListener
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:927)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1476)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:927)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1476)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
at server.WordGenServlet.generateWordDoc(WordGenServlet.java:85)
at server.WordGenServlet.processRequest(WordGenServlet.java:66)
at server.WordGenServlet.doPost(WordGenServlet.java:229)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.star.lang.XEventListener
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
... 43 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [`ridl.jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openoffice/ridl/) to your CLASSPATH. Don't know which version is suitable for you.